# How to fix Java applications mouse pointer offset in Awesome WM?

Tags: java, awesome

How to reproduce in Awesome WM v3.5.2 through 3.5.5 (so far):

1. Install OpenJDK or Oracle **Java 7**. This bug has been observed with both.
2. Start a new Awesome WM session with the **default configuration**.
3. Start either **jEdit** or **PyCharm**. This bug has been observed with both.

   - Move the mouse pointer around, and observe how it changes based on whether you are hovering over code, project files or menus. This should work normally.
   - Click and release on the *File* menu, enter one of the sub-menu, and observe how the item directly under the mouse pointer is focused all the time.
4. Press <kbd>Mod4</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> repeatedly until the **floating layout** is activated (the application will be almost full screen) *or* open another application in the same tag.

At this point, I would expect the mouse to behave like it does with "normal" applications. Instead I observe the following:

- When clicking and navigating menus with the mouse, the mouse pointer and the focused menu item will be **vertically offset** from each other, seemingly at the same amount of pixels as the height of the status bar.
- When hovering over miscellaneous items as before, the **cursor icon** will be set as if the mouse pointer was higher up on the screen. For example, hovering over the top line of text you will not see a text cursor.

It's as if something doesn't detect that the window coordinates have changed.

A similar but much more annoying bug happens when you **open another application in the same tag** - the mouse behaviour is **as if the window hadn't moved at all.**

When you **toggle another tag which already has an application open** - the "virtual mouse desktop" is moved to the **top left of the primary screen**.

Since these bugs have been observed in both OpenJDK and Oracle Java, with different Java applications, it seems very likely that the bug is in Awesome WM.

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999219/intellij-idea-under-awesome-wm), [article](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java). I tried the `_JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING` and `wmname` fixes, but no go.

Comment: I think the latest Awesome is a reparenting WM so the NONREPARENTING option should not be needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add special definitions to the source for the window manager, in my experience.

I had this happen to me a couple of years ago in the MATE desktop's `marco` window manager; the 'fix' was to make marco pretend to be its parent project, metacity, to utilize the JDK's built-in fixes for metacity.

from `src/core/display.c`:

```
meta_prop_set_utf8_string_hint (the_display,
                                the_display->leader_window,
                                the_display->atom__NET_WM_NAME,
                                "Metacity (Marco)");
```

This fix reeks of what happened to the user agent string in the world of web browsers, but it worked for me.

Additionally, the arch wiki even mentions Awesome WM in the section on impersonating other window managers, where it recommends `wmname`:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#Impersonate_another_window_manager

> You may use the wmname from suckless.org to make the JVM believe you
>   are running a different window manager. This may solve a rendering
>   issue of Java GUIs occurring in window managers like Awesome or Dwm or
>   Ratpoison.
>
> $ wmname LG3D
>
> You must restart the application in question after issuing the wmname
>   command.
>
> This works because the JVM contains a hard-coded list of known,
>   non-re-parenting window managers. For maximum irony, some users prefer
>   to impersonate LG3D, the non-re-parenting window manager written by
>   Sun, in Java.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be known Java related bug on Linux: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227754

On above URL you can find workaround for NetBeans IDE, workaround which works for Java app I use is to NOT maximize Java app by pressing maximize button, but to resize window manually to size you prefer. Please share info if this help you, thanks!

Comment: There is no button to maximize in Awesome WM. Using the [floating layout](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Layout) made it even worse (the entire window is grey until I change the layout), and "Open"JDK enforces registration even to look at bugs.

Comment: Actually, it seems openjdk.java.net requires users to print, sign, scan and email the Oracle Contributor Agreement to be a "contributor", which presumably is necessary to see their bug database. Guess the contents must be pretty horrific.

Comment: And setting `DESKTOP_SESSION` doesn't work. Tried with several of the suggested values.